# Do we want a Cyprus tag?

Tags: discussion

Methinks probably, but putting it out for discussion. In case the community decides we do need the tag, I've found only a few relevant questions:

- [Makarios III's harsh quote on Turkish Cypriots](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/53310/makarios-iiis-harsh-quote-on-turkish-cypriots)
- [During WW2, how fortified was Cyprus?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33883/during-ww2-how-fortified-was-cyprus)
- [Were Cypriots able to pay their bills during the "bail in" of March 2013?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42954/were-cypriots-able-to-pay-their-bills-during-the-bail-in-of-march-2013)
- [Has there ever been an archbishop or bishop younger than the 16-year-old James of Nicosia?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/48369/has-there-ever-been-an-archbishop-or-bishop-younger-than-the-16-year-old-james-o)

Comment: It is so weird that there has been so few questions on Cyprus, an island so ancient...

Comment: @buræquete: there are a few other questions that mention Cyprus in their body, but they aren't about Cyprus specifically. You can see them by searching [`Cyprus is:question`](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=cyprus+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: I'm good with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added the tag and edited the 4 questions I found.